# Stack OverFlow with inherited JPanels

Tags: java, inheritance, jpanel, stack-overflow

So I'm writing a program that is fairly expansive and had a stack overflow error (No, I'm not using any kind of recursion, at least not directly.)  I tried to recreate the situation with much simpler classes to see if it would also cause a stack overflow error and it did.  Here they are:

First Class:

```
public class Thing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          OtherThing thing = new OtherThing();
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class OtherThing extends JPanel
 {
     protected int s =5;
     protected String blah = "asfasd";
     public OtherThing()
     {
        OtherOtherThing thing2 = new OtherOtherThing();
     }
 }
```

Last Class:

```
public class OtherOtherThing extends OtherThing
 {
     public OtherOtherThing()
     {

     }
 }
```

This causes a stack overflow bouncing between OtherThing line 8 and OtherOtherThing line 4 (lines im sure are a little off now.)

I know that you can inherit from a class that has inherited from something else, the Java API is full of them.  Whats wrong with this example?

Answer (score 1):

Because when `OtherOtherThing` is created, the constructor of its parent `OtherThing` is called, which created a new `OtherOtherThing` , and inside this `OtherOtherThing`, it will in turn create a new `OtherOtherThing` ..., which cause stackoverflow.

You can use **lazy initialization** or **eager initialization** in order to resolve it:

Lazy initialization:

```
public class OtherThing extends JPanel
 {
     protected int s =5;
     protected String blah = "asfasd";
     private OtherOtherThing other = null;
     public OtherThing()
     {

     }
     public void initialize(){
          other =  new OtherOtherThing();
     }
 }
```

Eager initialization:

```
 public class OtherThing extends JPanel
 {
     protected int s =5;
     protected String blah = "asfasd";
     private OtherOtherThing other = new OtherOtherThing();
     public OtherThing()
     {

     }

 }
```

Comment: He never created an `OtherOtherThing`

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with this example?

The first thing a constructor does, unless otherwise specified, is to call the superclass constructor.

```
public OtherOtherThing()
{
    super(); // automatically added by compiler
}
```

So yeah, your code will continue to create new `OtherOtherThing`s until the stack overflows.